# Hive Migrate Date Format from Greenplum SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

I am looking for help to convert below sql query into hive supported date format. kindly assist.

GP: SQL

```
select to_date('19800302000000','yyyymmddhh24miss') date_of_birth
```

GP Output : 1980-03-02

GP query :

```
extract(year from age(current_date-1, to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) age
```

we are looking similar out in hive. please help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `select to_date('19800302000000','yyyymmddhh24miss')` use this
`select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('19800302000000','yyyyMMddhhmmSS'))`.

If you dont want time part, use this
`select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('19800302000000','yyyyMMddhhmmSS')))`.

For `extract(year from age(current_date-1, to_date(b.birthday,'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) age`

use below code. it should give difference of years between yesterday and DOB.

```
select 
year(current_date() - interval 1 day ) - 
year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('19800302000000','yyyyMMddhhmmSS'))) age
```